# Coalesce records in sql server when repeated two 2 times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have records as follow in a tables on sql server 2005

```
fname  lname  address  zip 
xxx    yyy     UK      001 
zzz    yyy     UK      001 
aaa    yyy     UK      002  
ddd    jjj     US      003 
eee    jjj     US      003
```

I need to get the result in the following format

```
fname    lname  address  zip
xxx,zzz   yyy    UK      001
ddd,eee   jjj    US      003
```

Basically every records which have a count address and zip 2 times will have their first name grouped and separated by comma.

Ok Here is my approach: but not working and stuck right now

```
select fname, lname, address, zip from table people 
where address is not null
and zip is not null
group by address,zip 
having count(address)=2 and count (zip)=2 
order by address
```

-- Now to coalesce the records I am using

```
SELECT fname = COALESCE(fname + ', ', '') + ISNULL(fname, 'N/A'), fname, lname,streetname, housenumber
FROM people 
WHERE address is not null and zip is not null  
group by address,zip 
having count(address)=2 and count (zip)=2 
order by address
```

Comment: what have you tried? Stack Overflow will help you to write your own query, but we don't want to write the whole thing for you :) If you can give us an idea of what you've done (even if it was just googling for likely keyword candidates) we'll be more receptive to adjusting it to make it fit your requirements...

Comment: Google `SQL Server Group_Concat`. Since Group_Concat belongs to MySQL, you will be looking for SQL Server workarounds for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a duplicate because it doesn't require anything like `group_concat()`.  The OP is specifically asking for *two* times, and you can get that like this:

```
select min(fname) + ',' + max(fname), lname, address, zip
from table t
group by lname, address, zip
having count(*) = 2;
```

Of course, a general answer with more matching rows can't be solved this way, but the question specifically says "zip 2 times".

Comment: Thanks gordon,  your solution did the trick :) instead of count (*) I just added count(address)=2 and count(zip)=2